# LTS upgrade to 18.04.1 stuck

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, lts

My LTS upgrade to 18.04.1 has been on "Installing the upgrades" for the last 6 hours on an Intel Core i3 machine.  Nothing seems to be happening except regeneration of kworker threads.  What's the best recoverey path?

Cmd line upgrade appeared ok, but reboot failed. Recovery mode showed welcome to 18.04, but login screen showed ubuntu 16.04 on a bionic beaver background.  Now i can't access the machine to do anything ...

Comment: you might want to kill that process, then run the following from the command line: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing` then run `sudo do-release-upgrade` then if you have any errors, you can paste them into your question

Comment: If you have Secure Boot enabled and DKMS kernel modules then perhaps [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dkms/+bug/1775672)?

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat : Conflicts: packagekit
                              Conflicts: packagekit:i386
E: Broken packages

Comment: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat is installed already.
If I install packagekit then python3-aptdaemon will be removed
Now I've noted this, I'll install packagekit ...

Comment: problem was in trying to use my default cinnamon desktop.  With Ubuntu selected, login was ok.  With gnome-user-share purged, cinnamon now works too - in software mode ...

Comment: On a super 8750 CPU, it was stuck for 1/2 hour at `rebuilding bamf-2.index`, but then it got unstuck :shrug:

Comment: It seems Bill had the same issue I just had, it took forever with the upgrade window fading in and out regularly. As i read his comment here mine actually sprung back into life, Im not sure what the issue is but all i can suggest is be patient and don't kill anything (62 minutes into upgrade before it work back up according to the time on the **top** output). Once it comes back to life it should take only a matter of minutes at to complete and give you the reboot prompt.