# Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index during dist-upgrade to 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

During distribution upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 the process logs `Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...` while "Searching for obsolete software" and a process called `bionics` uses 100% CPU for half an hour or more. What is happening here? Is it building an index or stuck? How long should I wait? Can I stop or suspend the process?

Comment: I have discovered https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065694/lts-upgrade-to-18-04-1-stuck#comment1816872_1065694 with "it was stuck for 1/2 hour at rebuilding bamf-2.index, but then it got unstuck". The orange progress bar seems to move at rare times.

Answer (score 1):

I found, like the discussions at [LTS upgrade to 18.04.1 stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065694/lts-upgrade-to-18-04-1-stuck#comment1816872_1065694) and [LTS upgrade to 18.04.1 stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065694/lts-upgrade-to-18-04-1-stuck#comment1874632_1065694), that the process will complete after some time. In my case it was well over an hour, while the orange process bar at rare intervals would move.